# Discord bot response based on a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I made a discord bot that when it hears the word friend it asks to be your friend, I want the bot to then look at the next message and if the next message contains the word "yes" to say a response. I tried using strings, but couldn't figure it out. Here is what I have written in javascript so far:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (!message.content.includes("friend") || message.author.bot) return;

  message.reply(
    "Did someone say friends? I want a friend. Will you be my friend?"
  );

  message.channel
    .awaitMessages((m) => m.author === message.author, { max: 1 })
    .then((collected) => {
      if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase().includes("no")) {
        message.reply("That's not very nice");
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TextChannel.awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages):

```js
message.reply(
 'Did someone say friends? I want a friend. Will you be my friend?'
);

// await the next message sent (in that channel) by the message author
message.channel
 .awaitMessages((m) => m.author === message.author, { max: 1 })
 .then((collected) => {
  if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase().includes('hello')) {
   // do something
  }
 });
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I run it: message.channel
   ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined

Comment: No. Should it be?

Comment: I'm getting an error message about there being no } for the { after the arrow function => and the ; after the token has red underline.

Comment: It has something to do with where you're putting the code in, not the code itself. Could you please put your code in a [Code Playground](https://playcode.io/) or something?

Comment: Sorry, I phrased my question badly. Could you *show* me the full code (in a code playground or something) so I can help diagnose the issue?

Comment: You just missed an extra set of closing brackets and parentheses. Add `});` on the line above `client.login()`